# highlight.js for latin language english

Tags: javascript, highlight, highlight.js

I'm looking for something like highlight.js but which analyzes and highlights grammar in the english language.

I would like to automatically highlight nouns and adjectives with javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The term to look for is **natural language processing**

One library to use would be https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp_compromise